# How to use git rm -cached to remove tilde file

Tags: git, version-control, gitlab

I have `~$itial Problem Description.docx` file in my git repo.

I'm guessing its a recovery type file for Microsoft word.

I added it to the repo and pushed by accident.

When I try and do git `rm --cached ~$itial Problem Description.docx`
It says - `'~ Problem Description.docx'` did not match any files

How do I `git rm --cached` this? And what do I put in my `.gitignore` to ignore it?

Comment: Did u try git -rm --cached '~$itia Problem Description.docx' ?

Comment: add ***~** to your .gitignore

Comment: add ~* to your .gitignore

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the shell is interpreting `$itial` as a (empty) environment variable because of the `$`. You can prevent the shell from parsing it by using single quotes:

```
$ git rm '~$itial Problem Description.docx'
```

Comment: I'm using `zsh` and this was exactly the problem.